# How to create a query where I can combine two tables on another sheet and add an extra column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Tables:
[image: The image of 2 tables]

I used

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:G6, ARRAYFORMULA("Company A") ; Sheet1!H2:N6, ARRAYFORMULA("Company B")}, "SELECT * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")
```

but it kept giving me an error.

[image: The images will show the resultant table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** *(the formula works)*
In your test sheet (the formula canNOT be posted, the sheet is in view only) you should use:

```
=QUERY({QUERY({Sheet1!A1:G}, 
           "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, 'company A' Label 'company A' 'Company' ", 1);
        QUERY({Sheet1!I2:O}, 
           "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, 'company B' Label 'company B' '' ")}, 
         "where Col1 is not null ")
```

---

**Original reply**

Try the following

```
=QUERY({QUERY({H10:L14}, 
           "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, 'company A' Label 'company A' 'Company' ", 1);
        QUERY({H16:L18}, 
           "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, 'company B' Label 'company B' '' ")}, 
         "where Col1 is not null ")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: #VALUE!
#VALUE!
#REF!
#REF!
#REF!

Comment: ***The original formula works***. It canNOT be posted in your sheet because it is in view only. It should be changed to edit mode.  In any case try the edited formula which is exactly customized for your test sheet.

Comment: editor mode on , thanks

Answer (score 0):

`VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` could be another alternative.

```
=VSTACK(
HSTACK(A2:G6,TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT("Company A|",ROWS(G2:G6)),"|"))),
HSTACK(A10:G14,TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT("Company B|",ROWS(G10:G14)),"|")))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2

Comment: @ConservativeLiberal `=VSTACK(
HSTACK(Sheet1!A2:G6,TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT("Company A|",ROWS(Sheet1!G2:G6)),"|"))),
HSTACK(Sheet1!I2:O6,TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT("Company B|",ROWS(Sheet1!I2:I6)),"|")))
)` See sheet `harun24hr`.